# How do I eliminate similar rows from my data set?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, data-analysis

I have a data set of about 90k samples and 140 attributes. After I split the data set into test and train sets, I am trying to build xgboost model. I am getting a very high accuracy about 99% which I think is error prone. I took first 100 samples from the test set and found the eulidean  distance with all the samples in the train set. And I found that there were many rows in the train set who carried almost similar values. Now I wish to eliminate such rows from the training set. How do I accomplish this task ? Is there some library function to do this? (finding pair wise euclidean distances and drop the rows below threshold) Please help. doing it for first 100 rows was kind of okay, how to do it for whole test set? is there any efficient way?

Comment: I hope you are creating the dataframe for the data points you have. You can simply filter out that by : df.drop_duplicates(cols='A', take_last=True)

Comment: @SijanBhandari true I have done that. But the function drops exact matches and not similar ones. eg.  consider <1.2, 3, 5, 87, 2.8> and <1.2, 3, 5, 87, 2.9> are almost similar and I want to drop one of them. drop_duplicates() won't do that I guess :-)

Comment: Sort by euclidean distance then keep the *largest* ```x```%?

Comment: Determine a distance threshold, mask out the data that does not exceed the threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scikit-learn's [`euclidean_distances`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) to calculate the pairwise differences to find similar values in your training set.

- Once you have the 2d array of distances, you can rely on numpy's [`fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) to eliminate the 0 distances where a row is compared to itself.
- Then simply define a threshold and create a boolean array to identify those values which fall below the threshold.
- To get the indices of the `True` values, use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to return the y and x indices.
- Now, zip the y and x indices, and use a set comprehension and `sorted` to remove duplicates (like [0,5] and [5,0]).

Finally, you have the pairs of rows which fall below a given threshold:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics

# setup dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(30, 5)))
print(df.head)

          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.778678  0.041665  0.149135  0.171045  0.522252
1  0.993003  0.503661  0.799485  0.279497  0.735382
2  0.153082  0.897404  0.279562  0.561585  0.213728
3  0.376735  0.445812  0.931879  0.450042  0.154132
4  0.517949  0.779655  0.486816  0.785099  0.194537

# get distances
distances = metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(df)

# set self-distances to NaN
np.fill_diagonal(distances, np.NaN)

# define threshold
threshold = 0.3

# get indices
y_index, x_index = np.where(distances < threshold)

# get unique indices
close_indices = {tuple(sorted(x)) for x in zip(y_index, x_index)}
print(close_indices)

>>> {(0, 26), (1, 10), (4, 12), (10, 18), (12, 14), (13, 27)}
```

You could now iterate through the `close_indices` and drop only one row each. However, some rows may appear multiple times. You have to take care of this.

#### Edit - MemoryError

With increasing data frame sizes, the array of euclidean distances gets too large to fit in memory very quickly (size n*n). Well, to avoid this, you can iterate each row and compute euclidean distances to the remaining rows. Therefore, each resulting distance array has a maximum size of n. In addition, generators are used to be less memory expensive. However, this solution is way slower because we have to iterate each row.

```
def iterate_distances(sub_df, threshold):

    def compute(sub_row):
        distances = metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(sub_df.iloc[sub_row, :].values.reshape(1, -1), 
                                                         sub_df.iloc[sub_row + 1:, :])

        y_index, x_index = np.where(distances < threshold)
        return ((sub_row, x + sub_row + 1) for x in x_index)

    row_count = sub_df.shape[0]

    return (index_pair 
            for row in range(row_count-1)
            for index_pair in compute(row))

result = iterate_distances(df, threshold)
```

`result` is a generator expression. You can normally loop over it. To show the results, you can use `print(list(result))`. You may improve the performance while iterating chunks of rows instead of one row only.

Comment: The above method is a cool Idea. But when I call euclidean distances over my data set I am getting a Memory error.

Comment: @NiranjanAgnihotri Updated the answer.

Comment: great! Is there any way we can parallelize this operation? Is there any such functionality in sklearn?

Comment: @NiranjanAgnihotri Please have a look yourself or open a new question as this is a different topic by itself.